# ImportError: cannot import name 'Input' from 'dash'

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm having this error when I try to run my code.. this error started to happen when I installed a new library, an auxiliary library of dash bootstrap components, this library:
[Dash Bootstrap Theme Explorer][1]

These are my imports:

````
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash_bootstrap_templates import load_figure_template
from app import *
import plotly.express as px ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Which version of dash are you using?

Try:

```
pip install dash --upgrade
```

Comment: `dash==2.6.2` I've tried to update but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.
I had to uninstall the 3 dash libraries I was using:

`pip uninstall dash`

`pip uninstall dash-bootstrap-templates`

`pip uninstall dash-bootstrap-templates`

and then install again and update:

`pip install dash --upgrade`

`pip install dash-bootstrap-templates --upgrade`

`pip install dash-bootstrap-templates`

`pip3 install --upgrade requests`